# PyMongo: Querying in muiltple arrays within the same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Suppose I have following entries inserted in a document.

```
     {
    "email": "test1@test.com",
    "primary_skills":[
        {"name": "python", "rating":4.0},
        {"name": "Django", "rating": 4.5},
        {"name": "AWS", "rating":3.0}
    ],
    "secondary_skills":[
        {"name": "Angular", "rating": 4.5},
        {"name": "React", "rating":3.0}
    ]
}, {
    "email": "test2@test.com",
    "primary_skills":[
        {"name": "python", "rating":4.0},
        {"name": "Django", "rating": 4.5},
        {"name": "SQL", "rating": 3.5},
        {"name": "AWS", "rating":3.0}
    ],
    "secondary_skills":[
        {"name": "Angular", "rating": 4.0},
        {"name": "React", "rating":3.5}
    ]
}
```

I want to find all the users(emails) given skill name, rating and type of skill (primary or secondary or both).

e.g. 1  find users with the rating above 3 in python and marked as primary skills. 
e.g. 2  find users with the rating above 3.5 in angular in both primary and secondary skills.

How should I write the optimal query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to filter the result.

1)

```
db.collection.find({
  primary_skills: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      name: "python",
      rating: {
        $gt: 3
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  email: 1
})
```

2. 

```
db.collection.find({
  primary_skills: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      name: "Angular",
      rating: {
        $gt: 3.5
      }
    }
  },
  secondary_skills: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      name: "Angular",
      rating: {
        $gt: 3.5
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  email: 1
})
```

working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/0A98YZtN6pv

Comment: In the working example, the second query is not working. Both the users have ratings above 3.5 in angular and it is only returning the second user ?

Comment: [this is working](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5K-EUDo_GA7)
Thanks for the help

Comment: your second scenario is that both primary and secondary should contain Angular above 3.5. neither of them satisfies this condition and because of that I've modified the documents and added angular to the primary of the second user as well, just for testing.